# JavaScript return won't update new value

Tags: javascript, return, var

I am trying to determine the distance from the top of the page in JavaScript, and I am faced with a Problem that the return command won't update the new distance.

I tried to get the distance like this:

```
document.addEventListener('wheel', getDistance);
function getDistance() {
   var scrollTop     = $(window).scrollTop(),
        elementOffset = $('#distance-check').offset().top,
        distance      = (elementOffset - scrollTop);
        
        return distance;
}

var distance = getDistance();
```

But for some reason it will get only the initial distance value and wont update.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Event listeners don’t accept a return; it’s meaningless. Variables don’t magically update; the `wheel` event listener has nothing to do with the `distance` variable at the bottom. This is not how event listeners or callback functions work. Please get a bit more familiar with asynchronous code execution. How are you planning to use `distance`, exactly? You have to use it inside the listener.

Comment: I am planning to use the `distance` var in order to pass from one scene to another with the THREE.js Library. sorry for my lack of knowledge with event listeners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the last line executes just once when the script is loaded.
When the event listener fires, it calls the callback function but the return value is not used.
Try

```
let distance;

document.addEventListener('wheel', getDistance);

function getDistance() {
   var scrollTop     = $(window).scrollTop(),
        elementOffset = $('#distance-check').offset().top;

        distance = (elementOffset - scrollTop);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do run the function each time the user scrolls, but you don't update the value :

```js
function getDistance() {
   const scrollTop    = $(window).scrollTop(),
        elementOffset = $('#distance-check').offset().top,
        distance      = (elementOffset - scrollTop);
        
        return distance;
}

let distance = getDistance();

// This is the important part
document.addEventListener('wheel', () => distance = getDistance());
```